# Makefile for checking spelling

Tags: makefile, aspell

I am trying to configure a makefile so that I can use aspell in it to check a folder of .mb files. I am not sure how to configure it but I tried this:

```
spellcheck-en:
    for f in src/docs/en/*.md; do aspell --lang=en check $f; done
```

The thing is, the makefile is not reading the $f so when I run 'make spellcheck-en' I get this:

```
Error: You must specify a file name.
Error: You must specify a file name.
Error: You must specify a file name.
Error: You must specify a file name.
Error: You must specify a file name.
make: *** [Makefile:29: spellcheck-en] Error 255
```

However, running this: "for f in src/docs/en/*.md; do aspell --lang=en check $f; done"  on the terminal is not an issue. Is there another way to indicate $f in a makefile?

Thank you.

Comment: You apparently want to check `.mb` files but you check `.tex` files instead. Is this intentional?

Comment: You should not use `@` before your commands, certainly not until they all work!  Please remove those so you can see what commands make is invoking (then cute and paste them here with formatting).  Also, please show the make command you invoked, the output you got (again cut and paste with formatting).  Saying "outputs Error 255" doesn't really help us much.

Comment: And if these are two different makefiles I do not understand what the first is supposed to do, sorry. What's the point in running `find` in a recipe line and not using the result? Please clearly explain what files (`.mb`, `.tex`...) you have, how many makefiles you have and how you named them, what command you type and copy-paste exactly the error message you get.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet The idea was to use the main makefile and invoke the instructions in the second one (the main one is the one that has all the useful invokations), therefore find that file and then doing the spellcheck. I also modified the .tex part and had forgotten to change it later (I got this from some instructions with .tex). I am not sure if I can just add the second part (the 2nd file's instructions) to my first instead. Now that I changed it to .tex I get this error: make: MB_FILES: No such file or directory. make: *** [Makefile:29: spellcheck] Error 127

Comment: @MadScientist I invoked 'make spellcheck' and since I had a typo, I fixed it (like you can see above) and it returns make: MB_FILES: No such file or directory. make: *** [Makefile:29: spellcheck] Error 127

Comment: Please edit your question (don't add important info into comments) and cut and paste the exact make command you invoked and the errors, with formatting.  There's no way you can get this message by just running `make`, if your makefile is really named `aspell-en.mk`; did you run `make -f aspell-en.mk`?  Also I can't see any way the makefile you've provided can give that error; it seems like you aren't properly expanding the variable `MB_FILES` so it's being treated like a target name.  Are you SURE your makefile here is an identical cut/paste of your real makefile?

Comment: @MadScientist Okay, I fixed it and copied and pasted the exact result on my question (the 255 one), since I had modified it while I was formatting it (that was why it was giving the second error).

Comment: You ask "any ideas how to do this" but you haven't explained exactly what it is you want to do.  Running `find $(CURDIR)/aspell-en.mk` in a makefile is the same as running it from your shell... it just prints the names of files.  It doesn't do anything else but print output.  As I mentioned above you must remove the `@` prefix to your rules: you're basically just throwing away all the output that would help you understand the problem.  I think you should write out, without make, the commands you want to run.  Then you can create a makefile that runs those commands.

Comment: @MadScientist I followed your advice and managed to make it work on my terminal in an easier way but it still doesn't work because of the $f (please take a look at the post again since I explain it better there)

Comment: `$` is special to make.  If you want to pass a `$` to the shell you have to double it to escape it, so you'd write `$$f`.

Comment: @MadScientist thank you, that works perfectly. thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is not about your issues which have been fixed in the comments. Your Makefile, while working after you'll replace `$f` by `$$f`, is not better than the equivalent shell script. It has 2 main drawbacks:

- if you run again the same check and the text files did not change, they will be checked again which is useless,
- the checks cannot be parallelized.

The following solves these two drawbacks:

```
# File Makefile
MDDIR   := src/docs/en
OKDIR   := .ok
MDFILES := $(wildcard $(MDDIR)/*.md)
OKFILES := $(patsubst $(MDDIR)/%.md,$(OKDIR)/%,$(MDFILES))

.PHONY: spellcheck-en
spellcheck-en: $(OKFILES)

$(OKDIR)/%: $(MDDIR)/%.md | $(OKDIR)
    aspell --lang=en check $<
    touch $@

$(OKDIR):
    mkdir -p $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -rf $(OKDIR)
```

If you now run:

```
make -j8 spellcheck-en
```

or just (because being the first target `spellcheck-en` is the default goal):

```
make -j8
```

You'll check only the files that changed since the last check and you'll run these checks in parallel with up to 8 jobs at a time.

Explanations:

- `wildcard` and `patsubst` are 2 GNU make functions.
- Phony targets are declared as prerequisites of the `.PHONY` special target. They are targets that are not real files. Make needs to know about them, just in case a file with the same name exists.
- `$(OKDIR)/%: $(MDDIR)/%.md | $(OKDIR) ...` is a pattern rule.
- `| $(OKDIR)` is a order-only prerequisite.

All these are well explained in the [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html).

Comment: Thank you, this sounds perfect. I get this error, though: Makefile:28: *** missing separator.  Stop. That line corresponds to this one: aspell --lang=en check $< . Any ideas why that may be? I read it's a syntax issue

Comment: Recipes start with a tab, not with spaces. So, if you copy-pasted you need to edit and replace the leading spaces of the **four** lines of recipes (2 in the pattern rule, one in the `$(OKDIR)` rule and one in the `clean` rule) by a tab.